# ext4 does not recognise journal device on boot

Tags: ext4, journaling

I have a system with a somewhat large md RAID5 which is presently running ext4fs.

The filesystem is running with an external journal, which is on another md (a RAID1).

If I add the journal device with `tune2fs`, the filesystem recognises it and it works.

Every time the system reboots, however, I get :

```
EXT4-fs (md125): failed to open journal device unknown-block(9,126) -16
```

I have tried identifying the device via UUID and get the same thing. If, at that point, I `tune2fs -O ^has_journal` and readd the journal via `tune2fs -J`, it works as it should.

This is obviously suboptimal behaviour but the only thing I found about it is a post in narkive by Theodore Ts'o - nine years ago - suggesting that yes, it happens and boy wouldn't it be nice if `mount` and `fstab` could be configured in a fashion where it didn't.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

There is the `journal_path=...` mount option that can be used for this, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html

If the journal device has a label, then `journal_path=/dev/disk/by-label/<label>` can be used to locate the device even if it changes device names/numbers.

See the original commit message for a better description: https://lists.openwall.net/linux-ext4/2013/07/31/24

Maybe consider submitting a patch to the ext4.5 man page to make this usage more clear?

Comment: I had tried journal_dev and for whatever reason it didn't work (BTW, the major/minor numbers have not changed since the external journal was created, so the 'not found' doesn't make sense in the first place - and because they are both md devices, it cannot be the case that the md device isn't ready and fails for that reason - as a matter of fact, / is also an md RAID1 on the same two drives as the journal).
I had not thought about using journal_path. I wonder if I could use that with /dev/md/journal1, which is generated by mdadm from the RAID UUID and therefore certain? I'll try and report.

Comment: So it worked! I did something a little different and put in fstab `journal_path=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<md device>` and it magically worked at boot.
I hadn't realised that you could use journal_path to point to the device of an external journal (as opposed to a file). Thank you!

Comment: Further comment looking at my notes: in this you have to remember that the same device will also have an md 'UUID', which only works for md BUT ALSO is the only 'UUID' that md will work with.

Comment: And a few more comments: experimenting, it turns out that there are multiple ways that work as long as you use the same format in  BOTH `tune2fs -J` AND `/etc/fstab`. You can use `/dev/disk/by-label` or, if you're using modern md, `/dev/md/<name>`. You can also use `/dev/disk/by-uuid` keeping in mind that if you `mke2fs` the journal again, the UUID will change.

Comment: Thank you!  I had tried tune2fs -J ... till my eyes bled...